# Fixing float:left and absolute positioning on two divs

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have two `div`s with variable width, that I need to display side by side. For this I made both `float:left`. The problem is that, for display reasons I need to use the first one with `position:absolute` and this messes things up, i.e. the `div`s overlap. I have tried absolute positioning the second one also (as seen in several solutions), but it didn't solve my problem. How can I make `float:left` work "as expected"?

([JSFiddle provided](http://jsfiddle.net/TaFfT/))

Comment: Unless the width of the absolutely positioned div is known at runtime you cant accomplish this in CSS (its not how these particular rules work), you may have to look for a JS solution. What are you trying to accomplish? What must the div be absolute vs?

Comment: And you can't float AND absolute position an element, that's asking how to make it red and white at the same time.

Comment: In the way you describe it, you can't. You could have a JS solution, detect width of absolutely positioned div at page load and add that as a margin-left to the other div. But it's messy and I would probably use that as an absolute last resort. I'd try to solve this problem a different way, for example, why does the first div _need_ to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: @ExtPro, fixed width is a viable solution. Would I have to involve `padding` or `margin`? If so, the trade-off would have to be in fluidity ("white space").

Comment: @MLeFevre, it was a radical (i.e. quick and dirty) decision, to vertical align labels and text boxes... I wish it were different.

Comment: If you have a fixed width, just do margin-left:xxx on the second component where xxx is the width of the absolutely positioned div

Comment: @AndreiV http://jsfiddle.net/TaFfT/1/

Comment: @AndreiV no probs will add it as an answer for obvious future ref for ppl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first div has a known / fixed `width`, simply adjust the `left-margin` of the second `div` to that amount,

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaFfT/1/.)

Comment: If the window gets smaller than the widths of the two divs combined (and no wrapping container), the second div would go under the first one but would maintain the "left-margin". I can, however, always do `@media` query and remove it.